# How to place equations aligned one on each line?

Tags: equations

I've been looking and trying for the past hour and I can't figure it out. I'm pretty new to LateX and I'm trying to display my Differential equations working but it's turning into a big mess.

I'm basically trying to get each equation on a line and aligned in the center. Here is what I've tried, but in vain:

```
\begin{equation}
    \frac{dx}{dt} = -r(x-x_{e})\\
    \frac{dx}{9} = -rdt\\
    \int\frac{dx}{x-x_{e}} = \int -rdt\\
    ln|x-x_{e}| = -rt + ln |C|
\end{equation}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome, you are using the wrong environment. Try `align` and put ampersands (`&`) right before the equal signs.

Comment: `Equation` is for one-line equations.

Comment: If you don't care about alignment, use the `gather` environment.

Comment: Strange ODE this is ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer the random 9 was to test if I was doing something wrong with the brackets ;) It's always good to have a single value for `tracing` purposes :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the `align` environment from `mathtools` here. Please have a look at the other small adjustments i made.

[image: ntuplyAlign]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{physics}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \dv{x}{t}                 &= -r(x-x_{e})\\
    \frac{\dd x}{9}           &= -r\dd{t}\\
    \int\frac{\dd x}{x-x_{e}} &= \int -r\dd{t}\\
    \ln\abs{x-x_{e}}          &= -rt + \ln \abs{C}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [`align` is part of `amsmath`](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Aligning_equations_with_amsmath), not `mathtools` (though since `mathtools` includes `amsmath` anyways, it doesn't matter much).

Comment: @ArunDebray `mathtools` fixes many bugs from `amsmath`, so i silently skip over mentioning amsmath.

Comment: Instead of setting up a completely new information system for starters, they should fix the LaTeX-Wikibook. I wouldn't even mind a really big *ShareLaTeX has fixed this page* on every article their guy updates.